# Encode-decode program

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a simple encode-decode program using ruby. The encoder works fine, however, I can't get the file to decode correctly. It always returns a blank text file instead of a nicely decoded one.
Here's the code:

Encoder, which works just fine:

```
# Get evil idea and encode
print "Enter your diabolical scheme: " 
$idea = gets
$encode1 = $idea.reverse
$encode2 = $encode1.capitalize

print $encode2
print"
"

#Save the jibberish to a new file
print "
File encoded.  Please enter a name for this idea: " 
idea_name = gets.strip
File::open( "idea-" + idea_name + ".txt", "w" ) do |f|
  f << $encode2
end
```

And decoder, which is totally screwed up:

```
#Get file to decode
print 'Name of file to decode:'
$name = gets
$file = $name << '.txt'
Dir[$file].each do |file_name|
  $idea = read.File($file)
end


# Print each idea out with the words fixed

$decode1 = $idea.to_s()
$decode2 = $decode1.reverse()
$decode3 = $decode2.capitalize()

print $decode3

#Save decoded file to new location
print "
File decoded.  Please enter a new name for this idea: " 
idea_name = gets.strip
File::open( idea_name + ".txt", "w" ) do |f|
  f << $decode3
end
```

How do I make the decoder correctly decode the text?

Comment: Just curious, why are you prepending all of your variables with a $? I've never seen that done with Ruby code before.

Comment: $variable is a global variable, as opposed to an @instance variable or @@class variable, right? That's the way I was taught.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Learned something new today.

Comment: I suspect at least one problem is that you aren't removing the newline after your `gets`.  Try `$name = gets.chomp`.  You probably don't want to use global variables (`$`) either; there's no reason to in this example, and in general, they should be avoided except in exceptional circumstances (but that's not why it's broken).  You can simply remove the `$` and use bare words as variable names (you don't need them to be instance variables either).

Comment: Yes, `$var` is a global, but whoever taught you to do that was wrong. We should only use globals when necessary, not to solve scoping problems or "because". `$var` is visible in any file you include in your program, and can cause problems if they collide with a global added elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Stewart. Adding `.chomp` to `$name = gets` fixed it. Works perfectly now!

Comment: I wouldn't say it works perfectly: I entered my name and when decoded the result was all lower case.  Room for improvement?

Comment: @LazyMonkey, That's true, I hadn't realized that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem I see is, if `$file` includes a wildcard (`*` or `?`) this code stomps on `$idea` each time through the loop, resulting in only the last file read to be in `$idea`:

```
Dir[$file].each do |file_name|
  $idea = read.File($file)
end
```

Instead, you probably want to wrap everything with your `Dir` loop so each file gets processed  in turn.

Don't use `$globals` until you know why you need them. Using them willy-nilly shows you don't understand variable scopes and are using them to work around errors in your code.

I'd rewrite the code to look more like:

```
# Get evil idea and encode
print 'Enter your diabolical scheme: ' 

encode2 = gets.strip.reverse.capitalize
puts encode2

# Save the jibberish to a new file
print ['', 'File encoded. Please enter a name for this idea: '].join("\n")
idea_name = gets.strip
idea_name += '.txt' unless idea_name[/\.txt$/i]
File.open( "idea-#{ idea_name }", 'w' ) { |fo| fo.puts encode2 }
```

and:

```
print 'Name of file to decode: '
name = gets.strip
name += '.txt' unless name[/\.txt$/i]

Dir[name].each do |fn|

  idea = File.open(fn, 'r') { |fi| fi.read }

  # Print each idea out with the words fixed
  decode3 = idea.reverse().capitalize()
  puts decode3

  # Save decoded file to new location
  print ['', 'File decoded.  Please enter a new name for this idea: '].join("\n")
  idea_name = gets.strip
  idea_name += '.txt' unless idea_name[/\.txt$/i]
  File::open(idea_name, 'w') { |fo| fo.puts decode3 }

end
```

I could have used `File.read` and `File.write`, but they both use "binary" mode, which doesn't translate line-endings. It's better to use "text" mode when reading text files for that reason, because then Ruby can do the right thing for the OS being used. `File.read` returns the value returned by the block, so I can assign it to a variable.

I'd recommend not blindly assigning `'.txt'` to the filename. Instead, look to see if it needs to be assigned. Sometimes, in the heat of typing away, we forget we *don't* need to type it, and then you'd be trying to read or write files with ".txt.txt" extensions.

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an example of how ideomatic ruby would look like:

```
# encoder.rb
puts "Enter your diabolical scheme: "

encoded = gets.chomp.reverse.capitalize

puts encoded

puts "File encoded."
puts "Please enter a name for this idea: "
name = gets.chomp

File.open("idea-#{name}.txt", "w" ) do |file|
  file << encoded
end
```

and the decoder

```
# decoder.rb
puts "Name of file to decode:"
name    = gets.chomp
encoded = File.readlines("idea-#{name}.txt").first.chomp

idea = encoded.downcase.reverse
puts "the idea was #{idea}"
```

Comment: Because you're using `readlines`, the code will only return the first line read in `encoded`.

Comment: exactly. it's just an example.